# How to fit content inside div element?

Tags: html, css, angular, position

I am trying to fix my content inside my div tag. I have only fit in some of the content inside it, but there is more that needs to be put inside it. I need help.

**Note** I am doing Angular but I need to fix my *HTML & CSS only.*

**My HTML**

```
<div class="contentBox">

 <h1>Please Type In Your Address</h1>

<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="addressData">
   <input class="addressBar" type="text" placeholder="Address" maxlength="30" formControlName="address" autofocus>
</form>

<a routerLink=""><button class="button">Proceed</button></a><br><br>
<a routerLink="mainMenu"><button class="button">Cancel</button></a>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.button {
    padding: 20px 30px;
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    position: relative;
    top: 28em;
    left: 3em;
}

.button:hover {
   padding: 22px 32px;
}

.contentBox {
    display: inline-block;    
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.addressBar {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    border: 3px black inset;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 3em;
 }
```

**Output**

[image]

You can see the two buttons are not within the div (in grey). How do I expand the div so it will be behind the buttons, providing the background for all the content?

Thanks!

Comment: i see the buttons inside the div in my code. please paste all of the styles

Comment: Are you sure there's no other styles being applied to `div`s that could affect this? From what you posted your `div` should extend to contain all of its child elements

Comment: I will add the rest of the styles.  EDIT I added all the CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace your `top` styles with `margin` as shown in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/saksham_malhotra/cnLrv87f/

By providing top coordinates with position relative, you are shifting your element position without considering the containing element.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using `position: relative` for your address bar and buttons. This shifts that element down by whatever your `top` value is, relative to where it's normal position is. I would use `margin-top` to achieve the same effect for your purpose.

```css
.button {
    padding: 20px 30px;
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.button:hover {
   padding: 22px 32px;
}

.contentBox {
    display: inline-block;    
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.addressBar {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    border: 3px black inset;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 3em;
 }
```

```html
<div class="contentBox">

 <h1>Please Type In Your Address</h1>

<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="addressData">
   <input class="addressBar" type="text" placeholder="Address" maxlength="30" formControlName="address" autofocus>
</form>

<a routerLink=""><button class="button">Proceed</button></a><br><br>
<a routerLink="mainMenu"><button class="button">Cancel</button></a>

</div>
```

[You can read more about the position property here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
textarea {
width:100%;
max-width:250px;
    padding: 0 0 80px 0;
}
.contentBox {
    display: inline-block;    
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.addressBar {
/*some style*/}

.button {/*button style here*/}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="contentBox">

 <h1>Please Type In Your Address</h1>

<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="addressData">
   <textarea class="addressBar" type="text" placeholder="Address" maxlength="30" formControlName="address" autofocus></textarea>
</form>

<a routerLink=""><button class="button">Proceed</button></a><br><br>
<a routerLink="mainMenu"><button class="button">Cancel</button></a>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not useful. It has what I already know, and I do not have a textArea. Please look at my updated answer.

Comment: Why did you put a textArea in your answer?